# How to get digits after the last / special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, digits

I need to get the last digit (the last number) from the string which contains a link.
For example from the link below, I should return the number `51`

```
http://radio-pendimi.com/website/index.php/artikuj/31-miresjellja-edukata-fetare/51-permbaje-gjuhen-tende
```

or from the followinig one:

```
http://radio-pendimi.com/website/index.php/artikuj/30-ilace-per-zemren-rukja/9137-jeta-me-allahun-ka-shije-tjeter,
```

number `9137` should be returned

```
$.each (path.item,function(key,val){
    //id_temp= val.guid.content.replace(/[^0-9 ]/g, '');
    id=val.guid.content;

    var tempDiv = $('<div id="tempDiv">' + val.description + '</div>');
    introImg = tempDiv.find("img:first").css({"width":"100%","border-bottom":"4px solid #cd1d1d"});
    var staticImg = '<img src="images/pendimi-logo.png" style="width:100%;border-bottom:4px solid #cd1d1d;background:#444"/>';
    output+='<div id="lajme">ID = '+id;
    output+= '<p style="height:15px;"><span style="font-size:13px;font-family:Bitter;color:gray;padding-left:7px">Kategoria: ' + val.category + '</span><span style="float:right;font-size:13px;font-family:Bitter;color:gray;margin:3px"></p>';
    output+='<a href="#artikujtFetar-full" onclick="showPostArtikujtFetar('+ id +')" style="text-decoration:none">';
    output+= '<p style="margin:0px">' + $('<div>').append(introImg).html() + '</p>';
    output+='<h3 style="word-wrap:break-word;font-family:Bitter;font-size:16px;color:#444;text-align:center;line-height:30px;">'+ val.title +'</h3>';
    output+='</a>';
    output+='</div>';
    output+='<div style="height:15px;background:rgb(210, 215, 217);"></div>';
    return key<3;
}); //lexo cdo element 1 nga 1
$('#shfaqArtikujtFetar').html(output);
```

PS: I need the usage to be in jQuery or JavaScript. It could be a Regex or a function, just let it return the result I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution

```
\d+(?!.*\d)
```

Usage

```
var s = "http://radio-pendimi.com/website/index.php/artikuj/31-miresjellja-edukata-fetare/51-permbaje-gjuhen-tende";
var p = /\d+(?!.*\d)/;
var m = s.match(p);
console.log(m[0]); // 51
```

[Regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/mY3aS5/1) | [JavaScript demo](http://jsbin.com/fizapogamuve/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: why it give to me double value?? The result is displayed as 51,51

Comment: @albpower Ok, check the updated answer; and use `m[0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
.*\/(\d+)
```

This will give the required ans.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cH8vN2/3

Comment: at the main post I updated my code can you tell me where and how to add this regex format?

Comment: @albpower  
var s = "http://radio-pendimi.com/website/index.php/artikuj/31-miresjellja-edukata-fetare/51-permbaje-gjuhen-tende";
var p = /.*\/(\d+)/;
var m = s.match(p);
console.log(m[0]);